# MongoDB aggregation grouping on 4 levels

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo collection of documents having 4 levels of informations (by importance):

-> client -> service -> expediteur -> tarif

```js
[{
  "client": "CUSTOMER1",
  "service": "ADMINISTRATION"
  "expediteur": "EXPEDITOR1",
  "tarif": "ECOPLI 20g",
  "enveloppe": "C65",
  "prixAff": 0.86
},{
  "client": "CUSTOMER1",
  "service": "RESSOURCESH"
  "expediteur": "EXPEDITOR2",
  "tarif": "ECOPLI 20g",
  "enveloppe": "C65",
  "prixAff": 0.89
},{
  "client": "CUSTOMER2",
  "service": "SERVICE1"
  "expediteur": "EXPEDITOR7",
  "tarif": "ECOPLI 50g",
  "enveloppe": "C65",
  "prixAff": 1.25
},{
  "client": "CUSTOMER1",
  "service": "ADMINISTRATION"
  "expediteur": "EXPEDITOR4",
  "tarif": "ECOPLI 250g",
  "enveloppe": "C4",
  "prixAff": 3.26
},
...
]
```

I'm looking for a way to write an aggregation pipeline that will present the aggregated data like this:

```js
    [{"CUSTOMER1":
      [{"ADMINISTRATION":
        [{"EXPEDITOR1":
          [
            {"ECOPLI 20g": { "qte": 57, "prix": 0.86, "totalAff": 49.02, "totalEnvC65": 45, "totalEnvC4": 12}}
            {"ECOPLI 50g": { "qte": 21, "prix": 1.25, "totalAff": 26.25, "totalEnvC65":4, "totalEnvC4": 17}}
            {"ECOPLI 100g": { "qte": 10, "prix": 1.46, "totalAff": 14.6, "totalEnvC65":0, "totalEnvC4": 10}}
          ],
          "EXPEDITOR4":[
    ...
```

the `totalEnvC65` field contains the number of times the `envelope` field contains the value `C65` in the data considered, the same for `totalEnvC4`

I started to write this `$group` element but it doesn't work

```js
[
  {
    '$group': {
      '_id': {
        'client': '$client', 
        'service': '$service', 
        'utilisateur': '$expediteur', 
        'affranchissement': '$tarif'
      }, 
      'qte': {'$count': {}}, 
      'prix': {'$first': '$prixAff' }, 
      'totalAff': {'$sum': '$prixAff'},
      'totalEnvC65': {'$sum': {'$eq':{'$enveloppe' : 'C65'}}}
      "totalEnvC4": {'$sum': {'$eq':{'$enveloppe' : 'C4'}}}
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this? Its your query with condition to add 1 if true else 0.
If this is not what you need if you can give us some sample data and the expected output for that data, so we try and test the query.

```js
aggregate(
[{"$group": 
   {"_id": 
     {"client": "$client",
      "service": "$service",
      "utilisateur": "$expediteur",
      "affranchissement": "$tarif"},
    "qte": {"$count": {}},
    "prix": {"$first": "$prixAff"},
    "totalAff": {"$sum": "$prixAff"},
    "totalEnvC65": {"$sum": {"$cond": [{"$eq": ["$enveloppe", "C65"]}, 1, 0]}},
    "totalEnvC4": {"$sum": {"$cond": [{"$eq": ["$enveloppe", "C4"]}, 1, 0]}}}}])
```